# what does bit_test() function do?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm reading [Programming in C, 4th edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321776410) by Stephen Kochan.

Exercise: Write a function called `bit_test()` that takes two arguments: an `unsigned int` and a bit number `n`. Have the function return 1 if bit number `n` is on inside the word, and 0 if it is off. Assume that bit number 0 references the leftmost bit inside the integer. Also write a corresponding function called `bit_set()` that takes two arguments: an `unsigned int` and a bit number `n`. Have the function return the result of turning bit `n` on inside the integer.

This is one of the exercise's answers on their [forum](http://classroomm.com/objective-c/index.php?topic=284.0).

```
12-5  
-----  
/* test bit n in word to see if it is on 
       assumes words are 32 bits long        */  

int  bit_test (unsigned int  word, int  n)  
{  
    if ( n < 0  || n > 31 )  
       return  0;  

    if ( (word >> (31 - n)) & 0x1 )  
       return 1;  
    else  
       return 0;  
}  

unsigned int  bit_set (unsigned int  word, int  n)  
{  
    if ( n < 0  || n > 31 )  
       return  0;  

    return  word | (1 << (31 - n));  
}
```

Now I tried to understand it like this and as per my understanding it always returns 0. What does this function actually do?

[image: like this]

Comment: For a few values of `word` and `n`, write down the equations on paper and solve them there. If you still have trouble understanding it then break it down into smaller parts. And if you *still* have problems also use the debugger to step through the code line by line while watching and monitoring expressions and variables. And if you still, after all the work you put through, still can't understand what's happening, *then* come back here and ask about it.

Comment: I'm, sorry if my above comment sound a bit harsh, but there simply are so many ways of trying to figuring out this yourself. If you can't do this simple example yourself, then maybe programming isn't for you.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm02C.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm02C.jpg @Someprogrammerdude I just tried that here. and I've included this in my answer if you read.

Comment: Lastly, the comment for the function *should* help you with some clues as to what the function does. Take this as a lesson to always make good comments but even more of a lesson to write *clean* and *readable* (and therefore maintainable) code and you would not have this problem.

Comment: Why don't you try it with a 32-bit number that has it's third bit set?

Comment: The code depends on implementation-defined behaviour and invokes undefined behaviour for certain values. It also relies on 32 bit `int`, which io not guaranteed. Said that: if this code is from the book (or the authors of that book), it sheds a bad light on the qualtity of the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just checks whether a bit is set or not.

It assumes that it unsigned int is stored in 32 bit on that particular system.

### Why the check?

Check is needed to make it safe ( I am not shifting a negative value or value greater than 31 ) As first one complains of being an error and the seecond one is useless as it returns 0.

### what it really does in `(word >> (31 - n)) & 0x1 )`?

```
x x y x x x x x x
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
    |-----------|
        8-2=6
```

(Here I considered 9 bit words instead of 32. In your case it will be `31-3=28`
So right shift it 6 bit

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 x x y
```

### Now how to check if it is set or not?

```
   0 0 0 0 0 0 x x y
 & 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
________________________
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 y  if it is set it returns 1 else 0
```

`if that bit is et the result will be 1 else 0.`

### What does bit_set do?

It returns that nth bit set.

```
So if you input 
0001 0010 1
and set bit is 0 (you want to set bit at position 0) then you will get
1001 0010 1
```

return  word | (1 << (31 - n));

let the word be 0001 1001 1
You want to set bit 2 [0 indexing]

```
0001 1001 1
```

|  0010 0000 0

---

```
0011 1001 1
```

You have to apply logical or operation on with that value.

#### How to get that value?

```
Here we just want this number
   0010 0000 0
     |-------|
         6 shift needed (left shift)

1 << (8-2) ---> is how you get it.
```

Or in your case `1<<(31-n)`

### Now I get what you are thinking wrong.....

```
You considered 25
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1101

The bit in 3rd (0 indexing) position is this
000[0] 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1101
```

This bit is unset or 0.

*Try 29th position of number 25 you will get 1 as answer.*

Comment: Hi @coderredoc thanks for you answer. 

as you mentioned 9-3=6. how does program come up with number 9 here? I think it's 31 - n (which is 31 - 3) in my example of word = 25 and n = 3.

Comment: this program always gives 0 when calling bit_test()

Comment: how come? You check it with different number and different bits...it can't be 0 always

Comment: @gonduriya.: I have explained everything I could....if it helped select my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement has us identify the leftmost, or highest order bit as `n = 0`, and the rightmost, or lowest order bit as `n = 31`.

The `bit_test()` function shifts the test bit to the lowest order position and does a bitwise **AND** to find if the test bit was set. For example, to test if the bit `n = 0` is set for the bit pattern:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

there is a shift to the right `(word >> 31 - 0)`:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

then the bitwise **AND** with `0x1` evaluates to 1, indicating that the `n = 0` bit was set.

The `bit_set()` function shifts a bit-pattern with only the lowest order bit set to the left so that only the bit indicated by `n` is set, and then combines this bit pattern with the input number using a bitwise **OR** to set the `n` bit. If the input number is 0, and `n = 3`, then the lowest order bit of the bit pattern for `1` (or `0x1`):

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

is shifted to the left `(1 << 31 - 3)`:

```
0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

and combined with the bit-pattern for 0 using a bitwise **OR**:

```
0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

The result is that the `n` bit of the input number is set to 1.